# Using an Autoencoder with uniformly distributed data

Tags: uniform-distribution, information-theory, autoencoders

Setup:

**Dataset**: 40k uniformly distributed 13-dim samples (floats between 0 and 1)

**AutoEncoder**: (input: 13dim) - fc layer 13 dim, relu - latent layer - fc layer 13 dim, relu - (output: 13dim)

**Loss**: MSE

I am using this toy problem to check if I can get a good reconstruction of the input data.

Using a simple AutoEncoder (just reconstruction loss, MSE), if i keep the latent layer of also 13-dim, I get a good reconstruction after 4k epochs.

However, if I reduce the latent dim to 2, I am having problems obtaining a good reconstruction of the input data even after 5k epochs. Visualising the first two dimensions, the reconstruction looks squished w.r.t. the input.

Does anyone have experience with such a setting?

I am not sure if the problem is with the data being uniform or there is another bug I should look into.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is perfectly normal because autoencoders are actually compressors. It's like you're *zipping* your files. If the information content inside your data is high, you can't compress it. There must be redundancies, which is typically caused by dependencies, and non-uniform data distribution. For example, if your image pixels are totally random, JPEG can't do much for you. Going back to original problem, you create a data with information content that cannot be efficiently compressed. The uniformity of data distribution makes it worse since every sample has the same likelihood. In the extreme case, think about a distribution where your samples are very much concentrated around zero. Then, the autoencoder can focus on reconstruction of those samples and catch redundancies better.

Comment: Just to clarify, by "I think this is perfectly normal" you refer to the bad reconstruction in the case when latent dimension is 2? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I meant that.

Comment: I reduced the dataset to just 10 samples, but cannot get it to over-fit when latent dimension is 2 (in fact any dim <8-10)


Shouldn't it be possible to do that? (Using AdamOptimizer, tried different learning rates and batch sizes)